# string equals false although it's true

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio as a web scraper right now. But I have an issue.

```
page_html <- read_html("http://competitie.vttl.be/index.php?menu=6&sel=36665&result=1&category=1")

> page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nth-child(3).DBTable_first") %>% html_text()
[1] "A [+]"
> identical((page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nthchild(3) .DBTable_first") %>% html_text()),"A [+]")
[1] FALSE
> page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nth-child(4).DBTable_first") %>% html_text()
[1] "B0"
> identical((page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nthchild(4) .DBTable_first") %>% html_text()),"B0")
[1] TRUE
```

A [+] always returns false and I don't know why. I compared it with someone else that returns true with exactly the same method. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Suggest you post a complete example.

Comment: Well, this is the complete example I guess. This is the code I am using for this URL: page_html <- read_html("http://competitie.vttl.be/?menu=6&category=1&sel=36665&result=1"). The code I posted earlier should work for tests.

Comment: Running the first line of your code gives `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.` So it looks like the page no longer exists?

Comment: You're right, something went wrong copying that link, it should work now!

Comment: That works, but running your 2nd line gives me `character(0)`

Comment: This is due to a missing space in the CSS selector string (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage is using UTF-8 encoding, which seems to be causing the issue.

```
library(rvest)
page_html <- read_html("http://competitie.vttl.be/index.php?menu=6&sel=36665&result=1&category=1")
grade <- page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nth-child(3) .DBTable_first") %>% html_text()
grade
[1] "A [+]"
Encoding(grade)
[1] "UTF-8"
Encoding(grade) <- "unknown"
grade
[1] "AÂ [+]"
```

Notice the extra character!

One solution is

```
 grade <- page_html %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1) :nth-child(2) :nth-child(3) .DBTable_first") %>% html_text()
 grade <- iconv(grade, "UTF-8", "ASCII", "")
 identical(grade,"A[+]")
[1] TRUE
```

NB converting from UTF-8 to ASCII removes the space, so the comparison is now to "A[+]"

BTW I had to adjust the css selector string in `html_nodes` to get this to work.